# hook django admin change-list editable save button

Tags: django-admin

We are using list-editable list to edit some fields of our model in the change list itself. However, we currently need to hook the save button of the change list to do some stuff on the changed models. Is there a hook for that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Well, since it has been a while with no response I will give some clues.  I had to figure this one out myself.  If you look at the HTML generated by the admin for an editable list it provides the "Save" button with the `name="_save"`.  So in your admin if you override the `changelist_view` method:

```
def changelist_view(self,request,extra_context):
   if request.POST.has_key("_save"):
       #Do something to if save was clicked.
       pass
return admin.ModelAdmin.changelist_view(self,request,extra_context)
```

you can then add functionality to the save routine.